# How to setup Bootstrap 4 Carousel with Craft CMS 3?

Tags: bootstrap-craft

I'm hoping to get some help or guidance on a issue that I'm having. I am using Bootstrap 4 as my CSS framework and wanted to integrate a working Carousel with my web project.  I managed to get the jumbotron working with a Matrix field. See below:

[image]

[image]

I was hoping that I could create a Carousel Matrix block in a similar fashion as the Jumbotron that was created previously. Any suggestions on a proper setup?

Answer (score 2):

A matrix field for an image carousel needs only a single asset field, one that will accept more than one image. In my experience there is rarely a requirement for anything more. 99% of carousels I have implemented look like this:

[image: An example matrix field for an image carousel]

If you wanted to add text to accompany each slide you could add a text field directly to the image asset and then display that with each carousel slide:

[image: A Craft CMS asset field]

Comment: Right, I just worry about the text to accompany each image for the carousel, since the 'Text' Matrix field is only applied once.

Comment: You could just attach a text field to image assets to create an image caption for each slide if you wanted. In my example above the text field is a separate block entirely, a Redactor field for entering standard copy, it has nothing to do with the carousel.

Comment: That's perfect! This would solve my problem. I was over thinking it. Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: No problem. I've expanded on my answer to include details for adding image captions. If you feel this is the answer to your question @egivensjr kindly mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.